# If $f:[0,T]→ℝ$ is continuous and $τ_0^n:=0$, then $τ_k^n:=\inf\left\{t>τ_{k-1}^n:|f(t)-f(τ_{k-1}^n)|=\frac1{2^n}\right\}\xrightarrow{k→∞}∞$

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity

Let $T>0$ and $f:[0,T]\to\mathbb R$ be continuous with $f(0)=0$. Now, let $n\in\mathbb N$, $$\tau^n_0:=0$$ and $$\tau_k^n:=\min\left(T,\inf\left\{t>\tau_{k-1}^n:\left|f(t)-f\left(\tau_{k-1}^n\right)\right|=\frac1{2^n}\right\}\right)\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N$$  with $\inf\emptyset:=\infty$.

> I want to show that $$\tau_k^n\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}T\;.\tag 1$$

Let's take a look at what's going on here:

- Let $$f_{\text{max}}:=\sup_{[0,\:T]}|f|$$
- $f$ is continuous $\Rightarrow$ $\exists t_1^{\text{max}}$ with $$f_{\text{max}}=\left|f\left(t_1^{\text{max}}\right)\right|\tag 2$$
- $f(0)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists t_1^n\in\left[0,t_1^{\text{max}}\right]$ with $$\frac1{2^n}=\left|f\left(t_1^n\right)\right|\tag 3$$ by the *intermediate value theorem* for all $n\in\mathbb N$ with $$\frac1{2^n}\le f_{\text{max}}\tag 4$$
- If $f\not\equiv0$, then $f_{\text{max}}>0$ and hence $(4)$ is equivalent to $$n\ge-\frac{\ln f_{\text{max}}}{\ln 2}\tag 5$$

Now, we could proceed in the same way for $$f^n_1(t):=f(t)-f\left(t_1^n\right)\;\;\;\text{for }t\in\left[t_1^n,T\right]$$ and $$f^{n,\:\text{max}}_1:=\max_{\left[t_1^n,\:T\right]}\left|f_1^n\right|\;.$$

> **Question 1**:$\;\;\;$If $f\not\equiv 0$, then $t_1^n>0$. So, in that case the set over which the infimum in the definition of $\tau_1^n$ is taken is nonempty. However, there might be more than one possible choice for $t_1^n$. Why does the infimum over all these $t_1^n$ exist?
>
> **Question 2**:$\;\;\;$In light of $(5)$ we could show that $$-\frac{\ln f^{n,\:\text{max}}_k:}{\ln 2}\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}\infty\tag 6$$ in order to obtain $(1)$, couldn't we? In any case, how *can* we show $(1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic seems rather difficult here. Instead you may use that a continuous fct on a compact interval is uniformly continuous so there is $\delta>0$ so that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<2^{-n}$. Then necessarily $\tau_k^n\geq \delta+ \tau_{k-1}^n$ from which your conclusion follows.

Comment: I'm sorry that I need to post in an old thread, is your conclusion still possible if we replace $[0,T]$ by $[0,\infty)$? $f$ is uniformly continuous on any $[0,t]$, but the infimum doesn't need to be an element of the set over which the infimum is taken and hence I don't see why $\left|f(\tau_k^n)-f\left(\tau_{k-1}^n\right)\right|=\frac1{2^n}$.

Comment: That's ok. It works also for $T$ infinite. The sequence $\tau_k^n$ is increasing in $k$. If it was bounded (in $k$) then it must converge so some $t^*$ and the condition for choosing the squence implies that $f$ must be discontinuous at $t^*$

Comment: What I've meant is: In your answer, you're using that $\left|f(\tau_k^n)-f\left(\tau_{k-1}^n\right)\right|=\frac1{2^n}$, i.e. that the infimum $\tau_k^n$ is contained in the set $\left\{t>\tau_{k-1}^n:\left|f(t)-f\left(\tau_{k-1}^n\right)\right|=\frac1{2^n}\right\}$ over which the infimum is taken. I don't see why this ensured.

Comment: The set is closed, bounded from below (and disjoint from a neighborhood of $\tau^n_k$). If non-empty it has a minimum.

Comment: That's the point. I don't see why this set is closed. For simplicity, consider $$M:=\left\{t>0:\left|f(t)-f(0)\right|=x\right\}$$ for some $x>0$ (and remove the assumption on $f(0)$ which is made in the question). Clearly, $$g(t):=\left|f(t)-f(0)\right|\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ is continuous and hence $g^{-1}\left(\left\{x\right\}\right)$ is closed. Moreover, $$M=(0,\infty)\cap g^{-1}\left(\left\{x\right\}\right)\;,$$ but $(0,\infty)$ isn't closed and we can easily find a sequence in $M$ which converges to $0$. So, maybe I missed your point.

Comment: Ok, the point is that since $f(0)-f(0)=0$ and $f$ is continuous there is a neigborhood of $0$ which is not in $M$. So you are actually looking at a subset of some $[\delta,+\infty[$, $\delta>0$ which is closed.

Comment: Okay, for completeness, your argument is that (since $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $x>0$) $$\left|f(t)-f(0)\right|<x\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\delta)$$ and hence $$M=[\delta,\infty)\cap g^{-1}\left(\left\{x\right\}\right)\;.$$

Comment: Yes, that's one interpretation. A perhaps simpler is to consider: $\{ t\geq \tau_{k-1}^n : | f(t)-f(\tau_{k-1}^n|=2^{-n} \}$ which is a fortiori closed and does not contain $\tau_{k-1}^n$.